# UEFI and RAID on disks above 2.2TB [AsRock Z97 Extreme6]

Tags: motherboard, raid, uefi

I have followed steps from the AsRock Z97 Extreme6 manual how to create RAID on disks above 2.2TB (manual says to use UEFI configuration instead Intel legacy RAID BIOS).

In few words what I have done (UEFI settings):

- disks configuration -> changed SATA to RAID
- went to Boot -> CSM -> Storeage OpRom Policy -> changed to: UEFI only
- went to Advanced -> Intel Rapid Storage Technology -> created RAID1 volume and left SSD as non-RAID

But when I go to the Boot menu and Boot Options I'm not able to setup SSD or RAID1 as bootable device (are not on the drop down list) so at that point Windows OS cannot be installed on any of those drive setups. Windows 7 installation states that any drive is not bootable. Intel RAID driver is loaded from the USB and all RAID disk are present there but with the message that Windows cannot be installed on any of them are not set as booting from. Message from Windows 7 installation process looks something like

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure the disk's controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu.

I have tried multiple times and cannot get any disk in the Boot Options menu when CSM switched from Legacy to UEFI.

Running BIOS version 2.50

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Best guess (hence posted as a comment). You changed the disk controller from AHCI (normal) to RAID. Windows has no drivers for that loaded, so no disks/arrays show. Press F6 and insert the floppy with RAID drivers, Then install in the newly detected controller.

Comment: Where floppy means floppy when on XP, and USB pendrive when on windows 7 or later. And yet something else on Linux or BSD. Please specify the OS used in the post.  (And possible remove the [BIOS] tag. Since the motherboard firmware is either loaded with the BIOS program, the EFI program or something else, but a 'EFI BIOS' does not exist. It is like a car running on regular fuel liqued gas.

Comment: @Hennes OS is specified in the OP. I will remove BIOS from it.

Comment: @Hennes Nope - I have USB with drivers - I'm talking about UEFI Boot options

Comment: Sorry. Missed that. I would go for AHCI and software RAID rather than fake RAID. Which does not answer your question. Will be interesting to see the answer on this one,

Comment: @Hennes I had same choice as a final solution - leave it as AHCI and setup a Windows soft RAID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of waiting I have got an answer from AsRock tech support

> Due to limitation of Windows 7 MBR, its limited to 2 TB (refers to Microsoft).
>
> UEFI mode installation could works with 2 TB or larger . (Windows 8.1
>   /10 comes with UEFI mode).
>
> To set up RAID, please try below.
>
> Delete the RAID in the BIOS (if applied).
>
> Load the BIOS setting default (press F9 in BIOS), save and exit.
>
> Restart the system, Enter BIOS again to set SATA mode to RAID, save
>   and exit.
>
> Press Ctrl + I when Intel RAID ROM prompted.
>
> Enter RIAD ROM to configure the RAID 1.
>
> Save and exit.
>
> Begin installing the Windows 7
>
> Note: Windows 7 only can create 2TB due to MBR limitation as mentioned
>   above.

Comment: You do understand that `Windows 7 x64` supports UEFI, right?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes sir